# Why does IMF still use analog tape for mission briefings?

Tags: mission-impossible

Just now watching the *Mission Impossible: Repercussions/Fallout* from 2018, and as usual, the mission briefing is on tape. The security system uses retinal scan, DNA test, but  they cannot upgrade the system to digital? At the very least it seems that would cut down on the physical size of the package.

Is there an in-universe reason for doing this, or is just for the sake of franchise continuity?

Comment: You can't hack tape.

Comment: You mean analog tape is less-hackable than 256 bit encryption?

Comment: Isn't it.? If you can remote access a tape then good luck but I suspect the *rule of cool* applies here.

Comment: So you are suggesting a remote-hack of a micro-SD is possible? Good luck on that one...sorry, this came after your edit of th e comment